# How does the eval() function change the dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, eval

How does eval() change the dict? This is an example: create a dict -> print -> eval -> print

```
>>> a={'a':'a','b':'b'}
>>> print(a)
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
>>> eval('a == "a"',a)
True
>>> print(a)
{'a': 'a', '__builtins__': {'bytearray': <class 'bytearray'>, 'IndexError': <class 'IndexError'>, 'all': <built-in function all>, 'help': Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object., 'vars': <built-in function vars>, 'SyntaxError': <class 'SyntaxError'>, 'UnicodeDecodeError': <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>, 'memoryview': <class 'memoryview'>, 'isinstance': <built-in function isinstance>, '__build_class__': <built-in function __build_class__>, 'copyright': Copyright (c) 2001-2012 Python Software Foundation.
All Rights Reserved.
...
```

Comment: Obviusly, it does. Maybe the question should be changed into "How does...", "Why does..." or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) is the globals used for the expression run by `eval()`.

One of things python does when evaluating an expression is ensuring that the python built-ins are available to the evaluated expression, and to do that it *adds* the `__builtins__` entry to that globals namespace.

So, yes, the `eval()` call did change your dictionary, and that is expected and normal behaviour. It even says so in the documentation for the function:

> If the *globals* dictionary is present and lacks ‘__builtins__’, the current globals are copied into *globals* before *expression* is parsed. This means that *expression* normally has full access to the standard [`__builtin__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html#module-__builtin__) module and restricted environments are propagated.

If you want to *avoid* this change, use an empty `dict` for the globals, and use `a` as the `locals` namespace instead:

```
eval('a == "a"', {}, a)
```

Comment: @xielingyun: you can look at the `exec` statement, but it's easier just to use `a` as the locals instead. Updated my answer.

Comment: Note: [The doc say all globals are copied on `eval()`, but only `__builtins__` is copied](http://bugs.python.org/issue22057)

Comment: can anyone please tell in which order eval changes the dictionary. i mean does it sort ?

Comment: @Cereal_Killer: `eval()` doesn't change dictionary order. Dictionary order is arbitrary and depends on the insertion and deletion history, see [Why is the order in Python dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15479928)

Answer (score 2):

The answer resides in [the doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) !

First of all, the second parameter to `eval` is the `global` dictionary. Than, we see:

> If the globals dictionary is present and lacks ‘__builtins__’, the
>   current globals are copied into globals before expression is parsed.

So yes, your dictionary gets modified by the call to `eval`.

Comment: @xielingyun Of course. Make a copy of your dict and give that into `eval()` and discard it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. The second argument to `eval()` is the "globals" dictionary, which explains what you're seeing.